# WindowsEventLogs not logged on Azure

Tags: azure, event-log, azure-diagnostics

I have an Azure WebRole with the following code:

```cs
public override bool OnStart()
{
    setDiagnostics();

    TestClass test = new TestClass();

    return base.OnStart(); 
}

private void setDiagnostics()
{
    string wadConnectionString = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString";
    CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));

    DeploymentDiagnosticManager deploymentDiagnosticManager = new DeploymentDiagnosticManager(cloudStorageAccount, RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId);
    RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = cloudStorageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(
        RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);

    DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();

    if (diagConfig == null)
        diagConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

    diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
    diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);

    roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(diagConfig);

    DiagnosticMonitor.Start(wadConnectionString, diagConfig);
}
```

In the constructor of my `TestClass` is the following code:

```cs
EventLog.WriteEntry("TestClass", "Before the try", EventLogEntryType.Information);
try
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("TestClass", "In the try", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    Int32.Parse("abc");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("TestClass", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
```

For some reason this code works well if I run it in debug mode with a break point on the `OnStart` method and running through the code with <kbd>F11</kbd>. However, I do not see any EventLog entries in my **WADWindowsEventLogsTable** if I remove all breakpoints and just run it. So this seems like a timing issue to me... Does anyone know why my code is performing this behaivor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried the exact same code and it did work. Would u please checked in your Compute Emulator UI if there any exception logged about MonAgent.exe this could cause the logs are not transgerred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `EventLog.WriteEntry()` method. I used the source "TestClass" as EventLog source. However I never created this source with a startup task and due to insufficient privileges it failed to log my entries.

So the solution: create an own source with a startup task or use trace messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `TestClass` creation from [`RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx) to [`RoleEntryPoint.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx).

```cs
public override void Run() {
  TestClass test = new TestClass();
  base.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it is deployed to Azure, does the role actually startup or does it just cycle between initialising and busy?

If it does the problem is to do with time.  The items are transferred from the instance to Azure Storage on a timed basis:

```cs
diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
```

if the instance restarts before it hits that timer, then nothing gets transferred to your table.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to make sure that you keep the application running for more than 1 minute.
2. You'll need to verify that the following setting is turned off (this might cause the logs to end up in a different place than you would expect them to, more information: http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/where-is-my-windows-azure-diagnostics-data/):

[image]